# No password required for user login

Tags: login, password, lightdm

I am running Ubuntu 15.04, but I have had the problem since 14.04. When i start the computer, the login screen shows up but i don't need to enter my password to login. I also cannot lock the computer, the screen goes black until i move the mouse and then I am logged in again.

I tried using sudo passwd [username] and set password that way, but to no avail. Also I have deactivated the automatic login. During my latest try I installed a new greeter (lightdm-gtk-greeter) I do not know much about these but this method also led nowhere.

For some reason on this computer I have a keyring program that I do not have on my Ubuntu laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use sddm instead of light-dm. If you don't know how to do this:

```
    sudo apt-get install sddm
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm && sudo reboot now
```

Then select sddm and hit Enter (or return) Now this keyring issue may also be a cause. Would you please leave a comment with name of the ring and maker?

Comment: The keyring program was called seahorse and is not something that I can recall installing myself. I uninstalled it, but the problem persists. I will try your solution.

Comment: @Freece Alright. What command did you use to get rid of seahorse?

Comment: I used apt-get remove seahorse

Comment: @Freece Instead of that do sudo apt-get purge seahorse. Purge 100% removes it